# Rank command in discord.py, error "Command raised an exception: KeyError: 10"

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a rank command for my exp system, but I have no idea how to do it, I've used several codes but none of them worked

Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def rank(ctx):

    with open("users.json", "r") as f:
        data=json.load(f)

    users = []

    for ctx.id in data:

        user = data[f"{ctx.id}"]["user"]
        exp = data[f"{ctx.id}"]["experience"]

        users.append(user)

        model = {"user":{user},"exp":{exp}}

    users = sorted(users, key=model[exp].__getitem__)

    print(users)
```

Json code:

```
"798263677051994212": {
        "user": "C1n0x#0001",
        "money": 3802,
        "experience": 53536,
        "level": 53
    }
```

when i run this command the error `Command raised an exception: KeyError: 10` is sent

Comment: Without seeing what that `data` file looks like, how are we supposed to help you find the issue? That `for ctx.id in data` doesn't make a lot of sense, and you're looping over the elements in `data` but inside of the loop you're using that to index `data` again - just use the element that you're getting from the for-each loop...

Comment: Since your id is saved as a string in your json, shouldn't you convert the id you're looking for in string ? ` for str(ctx.id) in data :` and same for your access to ressources, as `user = data[f"{str(ctx.id)}"]["user"]` and `exp = data[f"{str(ctx.id)}"]["experience"]`